# Azure Resource Manager: move VM to availability group

Tags: azure

Can't seem to figure out how to change the availability set of an existing Azure VM in the Resource Manager stack. There's no interface for it. Set-AzureAvailabilitySet does not exist in the Azure Powershell tools when in ResourceManager mode. It does exist in service stack mode. But that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, this feature may be addressed by the end of this year. It's a big challenge for the MS team to allow such operation. Changing the availability Set requires a review of the VM mobility architecture on Azure. Fore example, adding a VM in an Availability Set already containing a VM means putting it to different default domain. Becasue VM mobilty is a matter on Azure (No Live Migration), it's not an easy operation.

I have written a Powershell script which let you change the AS of an ARM VM by recreating it.
Give it a try and enjoy:

> #### How to use it ?
>
> 1- Download the script and save it to local location
>
> 2- Run it and provide the requested parameters
>
> or
>
> 2- ./Set-ArmVmAvailabilitySet.ps1 –VmName ‘The VM Name’ –ResourceGroup
> ‘Resource Group’ –AvailabilitySetName ‘As Name’ –SubscriptionName
> ‘The Subscription name’
>
> To remove a VM from an AvailabilitySet:
>
> ./Set-ArmVmAvailabilitySet.ps1 –VmName ‘The VM Name’ –ResourceGroup
> ‘Resource Group’ –AvailabilitySetName 0 –SubscriptionName  ‘The
> Subscription name’
>
> #### Download Link
>
> Version 1.01 :
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-Azure-Resource-Manager-f7509ec4

[Source](https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2016/02/25/add-or-change-an-arm-virtual-machines-availability-set/)

Answer (score 2):

That feature isn't implemented yet in the ARM stack, that's why you're not seeing the cmdlet...